# Android app exits to home screen in SOME devices

Tags: android, publish

I've created an app which automatically turns on Bluetooth on the startup. I tested it on 3 devices and it has worked perfectly normal. I tried to publish it on Amazon app store and they denied explaining that it exited to home screen and even sent me a video of that. I don't know what to do, where to test, it works normal but in other hand, it does not. Thankful for any help!

Comment: Probably some exception is occurring and the app crashing?

Comment: I use only btAdapter.enable(); to turn on Bluetooth.    is it ok? or it may create exception..